# Combining two rows from the same table and calculating total

Tags: sql, string, count, mariadb, case

I have a table with two columns, like so:

```
total | measure
________________
1     | private vehicle use
4     | private car use
7     | other
```

I want to combine the first two rows into one row, renaming the measure (strEUCategory) of the merged row to 'Private Vehicle Use'. I also want to combine the total.
I have looked into CASE and PIVOT but can't get it to work while also calculating the total.

This is my query.

```
SELECT  count(m.strEUCategory) as total , m.strEUCategory as measure
                from  laqm2_AQAP_measures  m
                where m.strYearIntroduced <=2020 and m.strCompletionYear >=2020
                group by m.strEUCategory
                order by m.strEUCategory
```

Comment: In order to combine rows - use `JOIN`. See documentation here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/join-syntax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `case` expression and aggregation:

```
select
    case when strEUCategory = 'private car use' then 'private vehicule use' else strEUCategory end as measure,
    count(*) cnt
from laqm2_AQAP_measures
where strYearIntroduced <= 2020 and strCompletionYear >= 2020
group by measure
order by measure
```

If you want more control on the new category name, then:

```
select
    case when strEUCategory in ('private car use', 'private vehicle use')  
        then 'Private Vehicule Use' 
        else strEUCategory 
    end as measure,
    count(*) cnt
from laqm2_AQAP_measures
where strYearIntroduced <= 2020 and strCompletionYear >= 2020
group by measure
order by measure
```

Comment: This works, thank you! However is it possible within that expression to rename the row to something new? It is currently 'private vehicle use' but I want it to show as 'Private Vehicle Use'